# Unable to find APP_BUNDLE_PATH. Cannot find a built app that is linked with calabash.framework

Tags: ruby, xcode, cucumber, calabash

I am running calabash-cucumber in xcode 5.0.1 on OSX 10.9.1, but getting this error while executing the test script. I have installed calabash framework successfully, but don't know why this error occurs.

```
Error... Unable to find APP_BUNDLE_PATH.
  Cannot find a built app that is linked with calabash.framework
  Please build your app from Xcode
  You should build your calabash target.

  Alternatively, specify APP_BUNDLE_PATH in features/support/01_launch.rb
  This should point to the location of your built app linked with calabash.
   (RuntimeError)
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.168/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_helper.rb:178:in `app_bundle_or_raise'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.168/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:307:in `relaunch'
  /Users/mymac/Desktop/myproject/myproj/features/support/01_launch.rb:29:in `Before'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your simulator or device contain the `YourApp-cal` target installed? Check weather you run the `YourApp-cal` target once from the xcode to install the app with calabash server on simulator or device.

Then Check you have followed [setup Process](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#manual-setup-with-xcode)
You need to have xcode tools installed too.

Check these things too.
Build the yourApp-cal target and run using xcode once.
While App is running open a Terminal(console) and type `calabash-ios console`. If your ruby environment is correct it will open you a ruby console.

In that console type

> server_version['version']

and

> Calabash::Cucumber::FRAMEWORK_VERSION

you should get something like "0.9.164"

calabash.framework is installed correctly in your app.

If so You should go to the file /YourProject/features/support/01_launch.rb open it check weather app bundle path is specified or not (if it is commented out calabash automatically detect the default app bundle path) if you are building your app to somewhere else than the default place you need to specify the appbundle path here in this file.

Tell us more details after check this list so we can help you more..

Comment: When you type Calabash::Cucumber::FRAMEWORK_VERSION on "0.9.169" it shows:  NoMethodError: undefined method `_deprecated' for Calabash::Cucumber:Module. --- possibly deprecated then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to set up calabash so you won't have this problem.
It involves creating a configuration, rather than a -calabash target. Basically you 
1. create a configuration
2. add calabash framework to that configuration in build settings
3. add framework search path to find that framework
4. create a scheme to run calabash

The longer version can be found
http://fangmobile.com/2014/05/08/do-you-love-calabash-ios-but-hate-that-cal-second-target/

Comment: This is helpful, but does not answer the question about what to do to resolve this specific error.

Comment: new link is http://fangmobile.com/2014/05/08/do-you-love-calabash-ios-but-hate-that-cal-second-target/   This is listed in calabash-ios github README.MD as one of the supported ways to setup calabash.

Comment: I've followed this tutorial and still have the same problem when I execute "cucumber" from the command line

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue, the way I got around to it is, on Xcode's top-right corner there is "Identity and Type" window. There you will find the full path of anything that you select on left (Project Explorer window). 
Now usually on the ProjectExplorer window you should have "Classes", "Common", "Frameworks", "Other Sources", "Product", "Resources", "Scripts" etc. (It might be slightly different project by project).  Inside "Product" is where your .app lives.

Select your app and you'll see the whole path on "Identity and Type" window.
Copy and paste it to "support/launch.rb" where it says APP_BUNDLE_PATH.

Should work now.

Edit 29/07/14: Do you see 
   `HTTPServer: Started HTTP server on port 37265`  on 'All output' window of Xcode (my version of Xcode is 5.1) when you build ?

Comment: This works, however using  "Identity and Type" to locate the absolute path turned out to be false for me. I used Finder on OS X to find my app. The path denoted in xcode was different then the OS path. It was off by a few letters:
 Xcode's "Identity and Type" displayed:
`...iphoneos/MYAPP-cal.app`
and Finder displayed:
`...iphonesimulator/MYAPP-cal.app`

By entering the path from finder resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the contents of `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and compiling again solved this problem for me.

My error message was `Unable to auto detect APP_BUNDLE_PATH.`